# How to change a certain block with air?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to get rid of all one type of block in Minecraft 1.10.2. I saw online that

```
/fill [X1] [Y1] [Z1] [X2] [Y2] [Z2] air replace [Block To Remove]
```

is supposed to do the trick, but when I did that the game told me that [X1] is not a valid number. I tried just deleting the [X1], but then it told me that [Y1] is not a valid number. Is there a different command to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

You need to replace `[X1] [Y1] [Z1] [X2] [Y2] [Z2]` with the coordinates between which you want to replace the blocks.

If you press <kbd>F3</kbd> to open up the debug menu, then look at a block, you can see its coordinates:

[image: Looking at coordinates]

You will need to specify two opposite corners of the cuboid that you want to fill/replace, as such:

[image: Fill coordinates]

I've used stone to demonstrate the area that is filled, but you'll need have `air 0 replace [block]` after the coordinates. With the coordinates added, your command might look like this, with different numbers:

```
1.12-: /fill 5 10 7 12 20 15 air 0 replace sponge  
1.13+: /fill 5 10 7 12 20 15 air replace sponge
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax you wrote was a bit wrong, use this instead:

```
/fill X1 Y1 Z1 X2 Y2 Z2 minecraft:air 0 replace WhatYouWantToReplace
```

Replace X1 - Z2 with the edges of the cube you want to fill and WhatYouWantToReplace with what type of block you want to replace.

Example: to replace all grass blocks with air in a 10-block area around YOU (or the command block that executed the command), use this:

```
/fill ~+5 ~+5 ~+5 ~-5 ~-5 ~-5 minecraft:air 0 replace minecraft:grass
```

Comment: The "minecraft:" is optional. It is used when there is a mod where there is another block called "air". For instance, if there is a block called "air" in the mod AirMod, you would have to use minecraft:air to distinguish it from airmod:air.

Comment: @EthanChapman Yeah, I use the `minecraft:` for that reason.

Comment: @EthanChapman Actually, no prefix automatically means `minecraft:` -- there is never a need to distinguish it. `air` always means `minecraft:air`.

Comment: What if I wanted to replace the air? If I swap `minecraft:air` and `minecraft:grass` it doesn't work.

Comment: @AaronFranke what? Replace air with grass? You can use this as well, but for 1.13+ `/fill` has a different syntax. Just leave out the `0` and it should work, AFAIR. Which version are you in?